# Inner Shadow Path Swift 2

Tags: swift, shadow, cashapelayer

I can't find an Inner Shadow method in Swift.

This is the image I'm trying to recreate:

[image]

So, I create a `circlrPath = MainCirclePath - 3` and Add shadow but it's not working.

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: viewRect.maxX-(viewRect.height/2),y: viewRect.height/2), radius: (frame.size.height-6)/2.0, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true).CGPath
let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor
shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowPath
shadowLayer.path = shadowPath
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 6
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
```

Comment: Did you add this 'shadowLayer' on your view?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Yes, I added to view with layer.addSublayer. If I set fillColor = white or anycolor (except  clearColor), its worked. But I want inside circle have some another layer.